# Set multiple radio buttons through the code(as checked)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

Please I want to know what is the problem in this situation:
If I have 2 StackPanels each one contains number of radio buttons

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton x:Name="RentingCK" Checked="RentingCK_Checked"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="SellingCK" Checked="SellingCK_Checked"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="UniversityHostelCK" Checked="UniversityHostelCK_Checked"/>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton x:Name="male"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="Female"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In my code in c# I want to set one of the radio button in each StackPanel

```
Female.IsChecked = true;
UniversityHostelCK.IsChecked = true;
```

The button that set is the last button I write it in the code, I mean, If I write my code as previous code above the UniversityHostelsCK  set and Female  unset and vise verse .
I hope you are understand my problem, and you can help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Set the **GroupName**-Property for OptionButtons to group them together. Right now all your option buttons are in the same group and checking one unchecks all other option buttons

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton GroupName="GroupName" x:Name="RentingCK" Checked="RentingCK_Checked"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="GroupName" x:Name="SellingCK" Checked="SellingCK_Checked"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="GroupName" x:Name="UniversityHostelCK" Checked="UniversityHostelCK_Checked"/>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Gender" x:Name="male"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Gender" x:Name="Female"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Very strange as i have tried the code myself and i didn't specify group names. And i didn't find any issue with removed check marks.

Answer (score 0):

U can simply do that inside the xaml with the IsChecked property:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="UniversityHostelCK" IsChecked="True"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="Female" IsChecked="True"/>
```

or in backend should work just fine with:

```
UniversityHostelCK.IsChecked = true;
Female.IsChecked = true;
```

Comment: For first solution I can not use case I have more than one case.
For Checked="UniversityHostelCK_Checked", there is some element will appear if the user check the university button.

Comment: I am using the solution in backend ,but the problem is when I set the second button the first one unset.
I do not know, What is the problem.

Comment: Can u give some c# code, so i can see where u are actually set these values ?